# Navigation Drawer Transparent Toolbar

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I wanna create navigation drawer with transparent toolbar, but I endup with shadow on toolbar like this
[image]

How I can remove shadow?.

I try elevation, but it remove all entire toolbar,

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mAppBarLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Anybody mind to help me?

Comment: Try using `app:elevation` instead of `android:elevation` and set it to `0dp`

Comment: inside appbarlayout or toolbar?

Comment: Inside the AppBarLayout. But there's some known issue with it not working on SDK 21 and above. You can find many solutions ranging from setting the elevation in the XML or programatically.

Comment: if i use app:elevation, its hide entire toolbar.

Comment: If that's the case, try using `.bringToFront()` on your AppBarLayout. i.e. `findViewById(R.id.appbarlayout).bringToFront()`

Comment: my sdk use API 25, how can i solve this?

Comment: SOLVED ISSUE THX

Comment: Hi @pekokbgtsumpah , how did u solve this? could u pls paste the style?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below code in `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
   getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
}
```

Hope this helps